# ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -942

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, impdp

Would somebody know what is that error?

This is during the impdp command and there is nothing imported.
The full error is:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-39065: unexpected master process exception in DISPATCH
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPU$UTILITIES_INT", line 1579
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPM$MCP", line 2710

ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -942
```

Answer (score 2):

Known issue:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4125750

[ORA-39006, ORA-39065 and ORA-00942: table or view does not exist When Starting DataPump in 12.2 (Doc ID 2341607.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2341607.1)

Rebuild the missing part by running:

```
catalog.sql
catproc.sql
utlrp.sql
```